# Binding a keyboard key to a Tkinter button

Tags: python, python-2.x, event-handling, tkinter

I'm specifically asking about binding a keyboard keystroke to a button in a GUI. Originally I planned to bind the keystroke to the GUI button itself, but that seemed impossible, and potentially unwise after I considered it later.

Is this the proper (pythonic) way to bind a keyboard key and GUI button?

```
## start.py
print 'start'

#from tkinter import *
from Tkinter import *
import os
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

class MyClass:
    '''This is my class.'''

    imgpath = '/Users/user/Dropbox/Camera Uploads'
    imgfile = 'susshi.jpg'
    #imgfilepath = os.path.join(self.imgpath, self.imgfile)
    imgfilepath = os.path.join(imgpath, imgfile)

    def __init__(self,master):
        print 'in __init__'

        # Create and load a frame into the tk (tkinter) window.
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()

        # Create and load two buttons in to the above-created frame.
        self.button = Button(frame, text="QUIT", fg="red", command=quit)
        self.button.pack(side=LEFT)
        self.slogan = Button(frame, text="Hello", command = self.f)
        self.slogan.pack(side=RIGHT)

        # Bind a key to each button from above.
        master.bind('q', quit)
        master.bind('f', self.f)

        # Open the image, resize it...
        self.image = Image.open(self.imgfilepath)
        self.image.thumbnail((600,600))
        # Make a tkinter-friendly image object ...
        self.display_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image)
        # Make a tkinter canvas, plug in the image, and pack the canvas.
        self.canvas = Canvas(master, bg='red')
        self.canvas.create_image(0,0, image=self.display_image, anchor="nw")
        self.canvas.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        ### FIXME: Set canvas focus!

    def f(self, event=None):
        print 'in f()'
        return 'hello world'

    def get_image_list(self):
        pass

    def next_image(self):
        pass

    def previous_image(self):
        pass

    def load_image(self):
        #stub
        pass

    def update_image(self):
        pass

root = Tk()
abc = MyClass(root)
root.mainloop()

print 'abc has been defined'
print '"abc.f()" returns "%s"' % abc.f()
#print str(abc.f)
#print repr(abc.f)

print 'end'
```

The intention of the project is to make a simple image viewer in python, with buttons in the GUI for basic navigation functions, and keys mapped to those same functions.

Comment: This is the *actual* code I'm using. I haven't implemented the other functions yet, and I was hoping to just get the code implemented thus-far reviewed. In fact, the original question was just asking about reviewing one specific portion of the code - that is, the binding of the keystrokes in association with the buttons in the GUI. However, that specific-level of question was downvoted and given a recommendation to adhere to the guidance in the help center. I understand there may be a common issue of incomplete code segments posted, but I have truly included the entire module.

Comment: This question [has been brought to attention on meta](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8756/what-happened-to-this-question).

Comment: [On the last edit](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/revisions/191477/8): There really isn't a GUI-agnostic way to ask this question. Each library will have its own way of handling button binding. An answer in PyQT would be useless for tkinter.

Comment: @StevenVascellaro interesting, I am unfamiliar with any other GUI options for python. In fact, I'd be open to suggestions with those other frameworks, if they are also pythonic - hence the leaving of the wording. Although I do understand the wording change suggestion (since my code was already using tkinter), I'd be open to the correction I see from time to time on SE of: 'Yes, it will work this way, but a better way is to XYZ.' I'm here to learn! :)

Comment: @user3.1415927 I'm using tkinter myself, but [PyQT](https://riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/intro) is a popular alternative. (See [Graphic User Interface FAQ](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/gui.html))

Comment: @user3.1415927 As a side-note, the term "Pythonic" can mean a lot of different things to different people. I've always interpreted it as a catch-all term for clean and easy to read code.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR**: Yes, binding the keyboard key and button to the same function is a proper solution.

## How to bind a keyboard key to a tkinter button

There are two ways to share a function between a `bind` keypress a `command` button.

**Method 1: Use an optional event parameter**

As you have already discovered yourself, you can use an optional event parameter that you don't depend on.

Since the parameter is unused, you can prefix it with an underscore (`_event`) to prevent warnings.

```
    self.button = Button(frame, text="Hello", command=self.func)
    master.bind('f', self.func)

def func(self, _event=None):
    print("Hello, world")
```

Full Example:

```
# from tkinter import Button, Frame, Tk  # Python 3
from Tkinter import Button, Frame, Tk    # Python 2

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, master):
       frame = Frame(master)
       frame.pack()

       self.button = Button(frame, text="Hello", command=self.func)
       self.button.pack(side='left')

       master.bind('f', self.func)

    def func(self, _event=None):
        print("Hello, world")

root = Tk()
abc = MyClass(root)
root.mainloop()
```

**Method 2: Use lambdas**

If the event parameter isn't being used, you can discard it by binding your key to a lambda function.

```
    self.button = Button(frame, text="Hello", command=self.func)
    master.bind('f', lambda event: self.func())

def func(self):
    print("Hello, world")
```

Full Example:

```
# from tkinter import Button, Frame, Tk  # Python 3
from Tkinter import Button, Frame, Tk    # Python 2

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, master):
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()

        self.button = Button(frame, text="Hello", command=self.func)
        self.button.pack(side='left')

        master.bind('f', lambda event: self.func())

    def func(self):
        print("Hello, world!")

root = Tk()
abc = MyClass(root)
root.mainloop()
```

(See [*How do I make Bind and Command do the same thing in tkinter?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30891865/3357935))

---

## Miscellaneous tips

#### Avoid using wildcard imports

You should try to be explicit whenever you import in Python.

Yes

```
from Tkinter import Tk, Button, Frame
```

Yes

```
import Tkinter as tk
```

No

```
from Tkinter import *
```

(See [*Why is “import *” bad?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2386714/3357935))

#### Switch to Python 3

[As coal_'s answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/191677/133295) mentioned, development on Python 2 is [scheduled to end in 2020](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0373/#maintenance-releases). To ensure continued support, you should transition to Python 3 or later.

#### Use strings when packing constants

This is more personal preference than a rule, but I usually try to use strings when packing in tkinter. It means you don't have to import as many things.

Yes

```
self.button.pack(side="left")
```

No

```
self.button.pack(side=LEFT)
```

Comment: Unused variables are typically named `_`. Prefixing a name with an underscore is usually done to distinguish 'private' names from 'public' names (those listed in `__all__`, or at least those part of the API).

Comment: @Coal_ I remember seeing unused `_` arguments suggested as a PEP proposal. Was that proposal ever approved?

Comment: As a PEP on its own? I'm looking through the list of PEPs now, but can't find it.

Comment: I may have been mistaken about PEP. I’ve found there isn’t much consensus on how to name unused arguments, but Pylint favors [descriptive names prefixed with underscore](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/139662/168744).

Answer (score 0):

> Is this the proper(, pythonic) way to bind a keyboard key and GUI button?

Sure. It's hard to judge exactly what you mean by 'proper', but it works, and I don't see any major caveats with this approach. Binding the callback to the button and calling `button.focus_set()` works just as well, but your approach makes more sense. Think about it: Does the callback apply only to the button? At least in the case of the quit-callback, no; no matter what widget has focus, pressing 'q' should quit the application.

Some other remarks:

1. Using wildcard imports (`from <module> import *`) is discouraged for a number of reasons. For one, using wildcard imports can cause conflicts if two symbols with the same name, defined in different namespaces, are imported into the global namespace. Secondly, for other developers, there's no way to quickly tell where an object was defined.
2. [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) proposes sorting `import` statements alphabetically.
3. Unless you have compelling reasons to use Python 2, switch to Python 3! Version 2.7 will only be supported until 2020 (see [PEP-373](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0373/#maintenance-releases)).